# Unity3d: "Platform StandaloneLinux64 with graphics API OpenGLCore is with HDRP"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to run a Unity3d project with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I keep getting the error:

```
Platform StandaloneLinux64 with graphics API OpenGLCore is not supported with HDRP.
Change the platform/device to a compatible one or remove incompatible graphics APIs.
To do this, go to Project Settings > Player > Other Settings and modify the Graphics APIs for Linux list.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

I try to follow their instructions, however I do not have an Graphics API List in my Other Settings.

[image]

Please let me know if any other information would be helpful.

Comment: Uncheck the "Auto Graphics API for Linux" box near the top and you'll have a list you can manipulate.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks! That was it. However, now the app just keeps freezing. As this is different than the first question, I will post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

@Retired Ninja's comment was correct:

> Uncheck the "Auto Graphics API for Linux" box near the top and you'll have a list you can manipulate.

I am now able to change to Vulkan. However, this produces a new problem that is not related to the original one, so I shall post the new problem.